# Python - How to run Hadoop stream passing command line arguments

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I need help for a school project.

For the labs I've did, I've written the mapper and reducer scripts in python (version 3) and I was able to run hadoop streaming with no problems there. Then I edited the script to process 2 files of a different format, and my script decides how to format the mapper data using the command line arguments I would pass into the mapper.py script.

The command line looks like this

```
python mapper.py abcd defg 1
```

Every time I pass it into the hadoop stream, I keep getting "python file not readable". I would like some help with this please!

Answer (score -1):

Replace the placeholders with the actual values for your specific use case. Here is a breakdown of the important components:

path_to_streaming_jar: Replace this with the actual path to the Hadoop Streaming JAR file in your Hadoop installation.
input_path: The HDFS input directory or file for the Hadoop job.
output_path: The HDFS output directory for the Hadoop job results.
mapper_script: The path to the mapper script or executable.
reducer_script: The path to the reducer script or executable.
: Any additional command line arguments required for your specific application, such as -file, -cmdenv, or custom arguments specific to your script.
Ensure that your scripts are executable and available on the Hadoop cluster's file system, and the necessary input data is present in the specified input directory.

When all components are set, you can execute this command on the terminal. This will launch the Hadoop Streaming job with the provided mapper and reducer scripts along with any additional arguments.

If you have specific additional arguments or a more detailed use case, please provide more information to assist you further.